# How to place a FormFunction in DialogInput?

Tags: gui-construction, form-building

`FormFunction`s work well in a notebook cell.

```
ff = FormFunction[{{"Count" -> "Number"}, {"Stuff" -> "String"}}, Identity];
ff[]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The following displays the `FormFunction` in the notebook and then the dialog with the result of the function.

```
DialogInput[ff[]]
```

How are they used in `DialogInput`?  I would like to create a dialog with the function and have it return the results of the function to the notebook.

Answer (score 1):

For a single page:

```
DialogInput[{x}
, FormControl[
    Dynamic[x, DialogReturn]
  , FormObject[{"Count" -> "Number", "Stuff" -> "String"}]
  ]
]
```

for a multipage, this is a very simple example but if it works for you we can try to generalize it:

```
Association[
  DialogInput[{x},
    FormControl[
     Dynamic[x, DialogReturn],
     FormObject[##]
     ]
    ] & @@@ {{"Count" -> "Number", 
    AppearanceRules -> <|"SubmitLabel" -> "Next"|>}, {"Stuff" -> 
     "String"}}
 ]
```

So there is a limit to crazyness due to the fact that `DialogInput` is blocking the kernel but we can launch separate dialogs for each page.

Comment: Interesting solution but it does not include one of the key features of multi-page forms.  That being the ability to pass-through the collection of previous selected values from all prior pages to the current page. For example `FormFunction[{{"Stuff" -> "String"},
 {"PreSelected" -> <|"Input" -> #["Stuff"]|>} &}]`

Comment: @Edmund I see, we can work it out I think, it is just a matter of the flow. E.g. instead of `@@@` you can `Fold` dialog over pages specs so it can access previous answers. Or  to keep `currentState` in an outer module and have it accessible for each inputDialog.

Comment: @Edmund I don't have time for it now but if you add a full example you'd like to be supported I will try to edit the answer sometime in near future, assuming you are fine with repeated dialog.

Comment: An actual example can be found here `Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/fh9zf.png"]`  I sent this to WRI support but they have not provided any workarounds as yet.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to show using `DialogNotebook` instead of `DialogInput`?  I tried the obvious but it still places the form in the evaluation notebook.